# Can Windows Service change its own password on start?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

**Question**: Is it possible to update the password for the windows service during startup of that windows service (in the C# implementation of the windows service)?

Background:
We store passwords in the vault. We have also windows service using accounts with password to log on. As the passwords change periodically, I'd like to query the vault to check if password has changed and if so, update the password for the windows service. I'd like to do that every time the windows service is started.

I used the following method to update the password of the windows service from a separate console application (from https://morgantechspace.com/2015/03/csharp-change-service-account-username-and-password.html)

```
public static void ChangeServiceAccountInfobyWMI(string serviceName, string username,
      string password)
{
string mgmntPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(mgmntPath)))
{
    object[] accountParams = new object[11];
    accountParams[6] = username;
    accountParams[7] = password;
    uint returnCode = (uint)service.InvokeMethod("Change", accountParams);
    if (returnCode == 0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Service account information changed successfully");
    }
    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Failed to change Service account information");
         Console.WriteLine("Error code: " + returnCode);
         // Support link to check the message for corresponding Return code:
         // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660(v=vs.85).aspx
    }
}
}
```

However, I cannot apply that for the windows service startup. It looks like the first thing is the log on with already specified password and only later the password can be updated from the code.

Comment: It sounds like you figured out the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have what you want yet. You could try creating a method that handles an event for when the vault is updated(if possible) and it will update the service's credentials then restart the service(if necessary).

I'm in a similarish situation, but I have one server that will be updating the service account passwords on other servers, the only issue is getting them to update their service credentials and credentials for running tasks once the account was updated. My current approach right now is using System.DirectoryServices to change the password on the remote servers, then putting the password in encrypted file on the target server. Then the service running on the target server has a filewatcher that will call methods to update the scheduled tasks and service credentials when that encrypted password file is created, and delete it after its done.